# Remove a link from HTML page before it loads with JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, removechild

**HTML**

**I was sure I was on the right track, but for some reason the code of javascript doesn't work and doesn't remove the second link, can someone help me please?**

```
<div class="p-4">
                    <h4 class="font-italic">Altro</h4>
                    <ol class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="#">GitHub</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function RemoveLink() {
    // Seleziona il secondo link (Twitter) e rimuovilo
    var secondLink = document.querySelector('.list-unstyled li:nth-child(2) a');
    if (secondLink) {
       secondLink.remove()
    }
  });
```

Comment: Works for me: the Twitter link is removed.

Comment: I have a lot of html before this, could that be a problem?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Nothing :/ :/ :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the part of the page you're trying to intercept is loading with some delay and that's why it's not working.
Try this solution. This code will keep trying until it succeeds in removing the element

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function RemoveLink() {
  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    var secondLink = document.querySelector('.list-unstyled li:nth-child(2) a');
    if (secondLink) {
      secondLink.remove();
      clearInterval(intervalId); // спира повторението на опитите
    }
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: I don't know what the reason is, but I solved it by changing last-child to nth-child(3), which is always the last